# joomla extensions zip then uninstall then install

Tags: joomla, components

I have been writing my own joomla extension and I am finding it annoying that every change I make, I have to zip my package up again, then uninstall the old one, then install my new package. I know I can edit in the joomla directory but is there a better way? Has someone already written something to take care of this? Thank you

This is Joomla 1.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install your extension once and then can make changes in code in files of your extension. You need to not to uninstall or install it again.

Or

use `<install type="component" version="1.5.0" method="upgrade">` this line of code in XML file of your extension installer. Then you need not to uninstall the extension, just install it over existing. It will over-write the files of installed extension with new one.

Comment: Just use FTP to upload the changed files.

Comment: I like the method="upgrade" idea, I did not know that. But it still sucks that I have to zip up the package. I am going to write a script that does a copy... then all I need to do is a double click :)

Answer (score 0):

Once your component is installed Joomla puts your component files in the correct directories. You just need to replace those files with the ones you have made changes on either via FTP or on your local computer if you have Joomla running locally.